# Understanding PDF CIDFonts, CMaps, and GIDs: Best Practices

Tags: pdf, fonts

I am trying to understand the PDF specification, and specifically the use of fonts in PDF, with a view to implementing a PDF generator.

I understand that the recommended approach now is to embed all fonts into the PDF - with perhaps a `/TrueType` font dictionary and embedded font program (all well and good). However, that limits us to single-byte encodings (and hence 256/255 characters in a single font). This is fine for most static, European-language applications, but becomes more restrictive when considering some Asian languages, and potentially even multi-lingual European documents with form-fillable elements. So, CID Fonts to the rescue (yes?).

What I understand so far: We map character codes (the actual text data bytes, which may use multiple byte encodings with CID Fonts) to CIDs (character identifiers), and then CIDs to GIDs (glyph indexes, as represented in the font file/program) separately. The character code to CID is done using the CMap file in the `/Encoding` entry of the Type0 dictionary, and the CID to GID using the appropriately named `/CIDToGIDMap` entry in the CIDFont dictionary. Either of these mappings can be the Identity mapping, which just maps the actual values directly, so character codes match CIDs, or CIDs match GIDs. (Separately to this, we have a `/ToUnicode` CMap in the Type0 font dictionary, which maps character codes - *not* CIDs - to Unicode code points.) Right then, so far so good.

It seems to me that a sensible thing is just to have it such that the character codes are UTF8 (or UTF16/32, maybe, to avoid issues of non-contiguous UTF8 encoding byte values?), and then map those codes directly to GIDs. If so, then it should be sufficient to convert the appropriate TrueType `cmap` table into a PDF CMap file, and then have the `/CIDToGIDMap` be the Identity. (And the `/ToUnicode` CMap becomes straightforward... right?)

Is this the right interpretation? The PDF specification isn't giving much in the way of hints on best modern practices.

I see a few options:

- Use UTF8/16/32 for the character codes, mapping directly to GIDs
- Use UTF8/16/32 and map to some pre-defined set of CIDs, and *then* map to GIDs (has the advantage of a potentially well defined intermediate step?)
- Use some specific, language-restricting encoding to just bypass some of this mess (is this actually just the same as the above?)
- Use GIDs directly as the character codes, and just leave the textual interpretation to the `/ToUnicode` map (although this just seems to be passing the buck somewhere else, and may not work with form fields?)
- Abandon the whole notion, and stick to single-byte TrueType font dictionaries (tempting, but unsatisfactory, as CID fonts seem to provide a great deal more versatility)

If you have any insight into how this problem is best dealt with, and if there are any standard strategies that I can take advantage of, I would appreciate your wisdom.

(I am already happy with reading in the necessary TrueType font files and tables, and accessing the TrueType cmap. I've also already got all the other PDF graphics operations working - I just want to be able to write arbitrary Unicode in my PDFs, darn it! Font permitting, of course.)

Comment: A problem with using UTFxx for character codes is that you restrict yourself to glyphs representing individual Unicode characters. Fonts may contain more glyphs, though, in particular alternative forms of the same character or ligatures (Unicode contains _some_ ligature characters but fonts can contain many more). Of course you may map such extras to Unicode private use regions, but that essentially would be a custom encoding, not plain UTFxx anymore.

Comment: That is a good point. Do you happen to know how that's usually implemented in PDF files? The CMap format might be able to deal with ligatures, I think (?), but I don't know about alternative characters.

Comment: It's very common to use **Identity-H**.

Comment: So then we're just using 2-byte GIDs directly as text data, and leaving everything else to the `/ToUnicode` CMap? That would make sense, as TrueType only allows for an unsigned 16-bit integer-worth of glyphs, so we would always be able to represent every glyph in a TrueType font (not that I actually expect any to have anywhere near that many glyphs).

Comment: That's a very common approach. If you have no troubles with non-ASCII'ish string contents in the content streams, it most likely is the easiest approach.

Comment: OK, thank you very much for the suggestion! I've got that to work - mapping character codes directly to GIDs, and getting the data back out with a `/ToUnicode` CMap. However, this raises the issue of how to deal with multiple Unicode codepoints mapping to the same glyph in the `/ToUnicode` CMap (for example, `space` and `non-breaking space`, but there are potentially lots of others). Is the only solution here, to allow both for alternative glyphs AND multi-use glyphs, to implement both a custom `/Encoding` and a custom `/ToUnicode` CMap?

Comment: The **ToUnicode** map is not necessarily a way to get back the string from which the pdf content was generated. In particular original Unicode characters that only differ in some typesetting implication (like space and non breaking space) may be mapped back to a single Unicode character. If you want to keep 100% the original string, you had better use **ActualText** marked content properties.

Comment: Right, that's a good point. The issue remains with what heuristic to use to _choose_ the Unicode codepoint for a glyph index (which therefore is also a character code) that represents multiple codepoints. My first thought is to just use the smaller codepoint, on the assumption that more common characters will generally have lower-valued codepoints. Is this the right kind of approach, or is there some other standard way of resolving these conflicts?

Comment: I'm not aware of such a way. That doesn't mean much, though, as I am usually on the other side, I usually have to deal with analyzing existing pdf contents, not creating new ones.